# Probability of photoelectric effect for gamma rays

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, probability, photoelectric-effect, gamma-rays

Why is the probability of the photoelectric effect occurring higher for low energy gamma rays? I'd like a physical answer not just equations.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a great question.

Comment: Agreed, a good question,  Pity I used up my votes.  I have never thought of that before...